# Why do Wifi speeds vary on two laptops sitting next to each other?

Tags: wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

I have two laptops sitting next to each other. On one of them, speedtests give download speeds of 50Mbps, while on the other, speedtests only show 0.07Mbps download speed.

Are the Wi-Fi signals interfering with each other? Or does the slow laptop have a worse Wi-Fi receiver? Why would this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: Most likely cause is something going on with the wifi receiver or its connection, eg: its connected to a different accesspoint futher away, but still within range so it did not switch)

Comment: The basic answer to your question is NO.  I have had two laptops sitting next to each other for months using the same access point (also nearby). Remake the wireless profiles on each computer to ensure proper access to the wireless point and restart both.

Comment: This can't happen. You should check your Wifi Adapter settings.

Comment: What speedtest exactly? "Internet speed" and "Wlan speed", have "nothing" to do with each other?!

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a lot of variables: Are they accessing the same AP? Which WLAN version are they using etc. not even starting on possible miss configurations, faulty devices etc. It's impossible to give a better answer without further, more detailed information.